# Linux fan control?

Tags: linux, hardware, fan

For some unknown reason, my laptop fan stays on consistently. Even when I'm using less than 2% CPU and the air coming out of the vent is seemingly cooler than the air in the room, the fan always stays on the highest setting, which is both loud and presumably bad for the fan. Is there some configuration file that can be edited to make the fan only run at a certain CPU usage, internal temperature, or something else?

Comment: Which laptop is it? Some laptops won't let you control the fan at all.

Comment: @Renan it's an ASUS X75A-DS51

Comment: Do you have fan control (using any utility) under Windows?

Comment: @Renan haven't used Windows on it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all check the BIOS, some laptops have settings that allow you to control the fan there. It might be set to "Performance" or similar which means it will always run at full speed.

Also make sure you have a reasonable CPU scaling governor. The governor controls CPU frequency scaling. Your choices are:

- **Performance** keeps the CPU at the highest possible frequency
- **Powersave** keeps the CPU at the lowest possible frequency
- **Userspace** exports the available frequency information to the user level (through the /sys file system) 
            and permits user-space control of the CPU frequency
- **Ondemand** scales the CPU frequencies according to the CPU usage (as do the userspace frequency scaling 
           daemons, but in the kernel)
- **Conservative** acts like the ondemand but increases frequency step by step

With **ondemand**, your CPU will only run at its highest speed when necessary. Ideally, this will be completely transparent for you, you machine will simply work as fast as necessary for the current tasks. To activate it do

```
sudo echo ondemand > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

---

If I recall correctly, the [Jupiter applet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jupiter/) can control the fans but I haven't used it in a while.

There are some laptop brand-specific utilities are for Dell and ThinkPads but they *might* work for your ASUS:

1. Try `i8kutils`. This package will install certain modules and programs that are specific for Dell fans and is very likely not to work on an ASUS. If it does:

   sudo apt-get install i8kutils 
   modprobe i8k
   i8kfan 0 1
2. There is a very nice utility called "[Simple ThinkPad Fan Control](https://github.com/Stanko/ThinkPad-Fan-Control)" which allows you to fine tune the trigger temperatures that change the fan's speed. No idea if it will work on an ASUS but it might be worth a try.

**DISCLAIMER**: I have only used these with their respective laptop brands. While the worst case scenario is probably that they just won't work, for all I know they *could* cause the machine to explode and rip a hole in space time. I have never tried on a non-DELL or non-ThinkPad laptop so try them at your own risk.

---

A couple of other things you could try are

1. ([source](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=90485&p=525285&hilit=i915.i915_enable_rc6=1#p525285)) At the grub menu press <kbd>e</kbd> and navigate to the line with splash (or nosplash) and insert `pcie_aspm=force` and `i915.i915_enable_rc6=1`

   If it works as expected and no system instability occurs (there's only a small risk) then make these changes permanent by adding them to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variable `/etc/default/grub`
2. ([source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1059548&page=2?)) add `acpi_osi="Linux"` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variable `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: I couldn't find any options in my BIOS, and the `scaling_governor` is already set to ondemand. Jupiter seems to be very redhat-specific (only options are RPM files or source with "mkrpm" and a non-functional python script in `jupiter/usr/bin`). It seems safer to avoid the model specific utilities, and my Wi-Fi already doesn't work with Linux on this laptop, so I'd prefer not to screw with hardware settings in any way I don't know how to reverse, as the disclaimer said.

Comment: @tkbx what distro are you using and which kernel? There was a bug in some of the older ones that should be fixed in the >=3.3 series. Anyway, have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: I'm running Crunchbang (Debian), with kernel version 3.2.0-4. Can the kernel be safely updated without reinstalling the system?

Comment: As far as the second other thing, I'm confused as to what exactly I'm supposed to do. Should I add `acpi_osi="Linux"` under `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`?

Comment: No, you should have something like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"`. I should also mention that I am just repeating things I found when trying to solve a similar problem a while back. I am not an expert on this and you should trust them no more than you trust the sources I give for each of them. As for updating the kernel, in general it is perfectly safe to update the kernel without reinstalling. Can't guarantee this will solve anything but it is not that risky either.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same fan problem on my Asus X75A. It would appear to be a hardware bug on a number of Asus laptops as reported here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upower/+bug/1088146

The short workaround:

Turn off the laptop, remove the battery for a few seconds, re-assemble and turn back on. This bug would appear to go hand in hand with the battery refusing to charge.