# My Laptop Fans drive me crazy on linux and much less battery

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery, fan

I have a Vaio VPCEA36FG laptop and both windows.8 and elementary OS (ubuntu 12.04 kernel) installed on it.
when I am in windows everything is just fine, fans work perfectly efficient and my battery lasts at least two and a half hours.
but in linux I have very loud fans working at high speed and very low battery life (something between 45 mins and 1 hour) which I believe most of it are wasted by unwarranted fan speed.

I tried jupiter, flgrx drivers and a bunch of other packages that I can not even recall names of them. but nothing works and I still have loud fans and It drives me crazy.

any suggestion?

Comment: What [governor](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88137/22222) do you have set?

Comment: Have you tried to see what [powertop](https://01.org/powertop/) has to say? (There's an Ubuntu package.)

Comment: I am using a System76 GAZP8 and I have hit that problem also. Boot one OS and everything is fine, boot another and the fans run full tilt. Found by accident that I had hit `Fn 1` instead of `Fn F1`. On my machine there is an documented Fn key that turns the fans up high. I'm still looking for a list of similar keys

Answer (score 1):

Here are two things you could try:

1. I see you notebook has AMD graphics. Have you installed the proprietary drivers? (fglrx). If not you should proceed to do so. At least on Ubuntu 12.04 they have far superior power management to the open-source ones. You can install them from the "Additional Drivers" menu or its equivalent in elementary OS. **Edit**: I see you have tried this option already. Well, I'd advise you to stay with the drivers for now. You won't get any better power management for your graphics card on 12.04.
2. Jupiter is obsolete. Follow the instructions in [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter) and install TLP on your system, instead.